# Apple Watch & Fitbit Watch With native Swift App

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, apple-watch, healthkit, fitbit

I want to develop an iOS Swift based iPhone Application (not apple with App)
That will sync with smart wearable Like Apple Watch and Fitbit smart bands and get info like heart beat and distance travelled

I did R&D how to connect watches I found **Health Kit & Core bluetooth Framework** I am a noob to both.

1. Do health kit will only work with Apple Watch ? not with other smart watches ?
2. if I use health kit for Apple Watch will I be able to calculate heart beat and Distance value on the fly ?
3. For other watches like Fitbit, MI Bands how can I get require info from them ?

I tried using core bluetooth framework to connect those watches as soon as I pass "OX180D" which is for heart tracking sensor it just stop showing me my MI Band in list of available peripherals

What would be the exact flow I can work to achieve my target
Flow Diagram or code will be really helpful.

Comment: What you want to achieve must be 2 different perspectives. One is collect health data and store, and the other is to access the data. Health Kit is kind of data center where you can store or fetch health data if you acquire appropriate permission from users.

Comment: I want to achieve is fetch health data from Apple Watch and Fitbit smart watch and save in my app core data

Comment: If you have your own watch os app, you can collect data from user's watch and store them to the health kit. Also if user is using Fitbit and has iOS app, and allowed to store the data to health kit(if there is a Fitbit app and it has that kind of feature), you can access the data.

Comment: just like MI App available it can connect with mi watch and also with Fitbit. Do using Core Bluetooth will allow me to get information from them ?

Comment: You can't get health data from Apple Watch directly without your own watch os app. You must have your own watch os app, or you have to use health kit data which other app collected.

Comment: Yes you can get data from the bluetooth devices, but in this case you don't need to use health kit at all. You just get the raw data from the devices and store them in your own CoreDB.

Comment: Okay for Apple Watch I can access health kit what about other for other watches ? Do I need to connect with their specific application ? can't we just directly access them ?

Comment: Raw Data Like ?

Comment: Yes I want to collect data and save in my own DB. Can you just please show me roughly what will be the flow to get data? like connect peripheral first next is to access its characteristics how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Do health kit will only work with Apple Watch ? not with other smart
    watches ? 
 2. if I use health kit for Apple Watch will I be able to
    calculate heart beat and Distance value on the fly ? 
 3. For other
    watches like Fitbit, MI Bands how can I get require info from them ?
```

1. HealthKit works with other apps, provided the other apps write data into it. It doesn't work directly with any device. The Apple Watch app writes watch data into health kit. Similarly, if Fitbit/Miband have apps that write into healthkit, then you as a developer can access this data, if your app has read access to healthkit data
2. On the fly is not possible. Right now, your app can access heart rate like a workout does, if your app has a workout feature. Otherwise you can poll the historic heart rate (that's taken once ever 5-10 mins I think).
3. You'll have to look into documentation for these devices to see if they provide access third party developers through APIs/SDKs to these devices/apps.